# How to execute a different statement for selected & non selected csv files using shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell

Currently i am working on some shell scripting task. I am in learning phase. My requirement is i have a lot of csv files in a directory example 100. In that 100 csv files, whichever file name starts with login i need to split the data and copied to different folders. Remaining csv which doesn't start with login as prefix i need to copy to different folder without splitting the data.

Examples : usr/myprofiles/test01.csv, usr/myprofiles/login.csv

.
Expected output :
test01.csv - Copy to different folder

```
              login.csv - Split the data and copy to different folder.
```

Currently i have written below code but it's not working as expected. Could someone help here to fix this script.

```
#!/bin/bash

count = 2
FILENAME = test
for dir in /usr/myprofiles/*.csv
do
  if[-f $*Login*.csv]
  then
        split -l $count $login.csv xyz
        n=1
        for f in xyz*             
        do    
             cat $f >> /usr/myprofiles/test/$FILENAME${n}   
             rm $f                  
      ((n++))                 
        done
  fi
  else
    cp "$dir" "$usr/myprofiles/test/$FILENAME$
done
```

Getting syntax error near unexpected token "then".

Comment: Syntactically speaking, you are missing the `if`. Paste your code into [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/), and come back after fixing all problems mentioned there, if it still does not work.

Comment: yes sure i will try to shellcheck.. Meanwhile if you check the logic is correct or not that would be helpful

Comment: I don't really understand the logic of your script. Even if we let aside the many obvious syntax errors / typos, it is conspicuous that you assign a variable named `dir`, but never thest whether this file starts with the word _Login_. I suggest that you first get it error free, then run it with `set -x` enabled to get a trace, and if there is one concrete part in the trace which you don't understand, ask about this.

Comment: To a start with, `count = 2` does not make sense. It executes a program named `count` with parameters `=` and `2`.  To set a variable to some value, use i.e. `count=2` or `typeset -i count=2`, if you prefer. But even then I don't understand what `split -l $count ...` is supposed to do. I wonder whether you ever read the _man-page_ for `split`.

Comment: ya thanks for your comment. i am just learning Shell scripting. i will improve it.

Comment: Similarily `if[-f $*Login*.csv]` is understood as running a program named `if[-f`,  and even if your script were syntactically correct, you would et a _command not found_ from this. If you are new to bash programming, it could help learning it by following one of the many tutorials available, before starting to write a larger program by yourself.

Comment: For instance you could look at `https://linuxconfig.org/bash-scripting-tutorial-for-beginners` (and scroll down to the section called **Variables**). This could give you a start. [This](https://www.w3schools.io/terminal/bash-variables/) too is helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure if you mean "copy" (for non-login) or "move".  If you don't move, you will be doing copies of the same files over and over again.  Similarly for the "login" files.  You will be processing the same input repeatedly, at ever run of the script, unless you eventually purge the input files.

Comment: When the output is not as you expect, always provide a FULL listing of what output is being generated, including error messages.

Answer (score 0):

This code segment is problematic:

```
if[-f $*Login*.csv]
then
    split -l $count $login.csv xyz
```

The above shows a misunderstanding of what the first "**for**" statement is doing (there is no implicit "**cd**" into the directories listed).  There is **no path specification** for the proper location of the "login" files.  It is looking for those files in the script startup directory.  The "login" references do NOT include that full path.

So ... you need to either

- add the path to the variable reference/usage,
- redefine the variable to include that path prefix, or
- perform a cd into the directory

in order to locate and process the actual login files.